# Не вызывается метод контроллера

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mvc

**Модель**

```
public class Checklist
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public Check Check { get; set; }

    public List<Check> Checks { get; set; }
}

public class Check
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

**Метод контроллера**
ChecklistsController.cs

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GenerateChecks(Checklist checklist)
{
    if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
    {
        Check check = new Check();
        check.Value = checklist.Check.Value;

        if (checklist.Checks == null)
        {
            checklist.Checks = new List<Check>();
        }

        checklist.Checks.Add(check);

        return PartialView("_checklist", checklist);
    }
    return PartialView("_checklist", checklist);
}
```

**Представление**
Create.cshtml

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/add_check.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <h4>New Checklist</h4>

    <table class="table table-bordered" id="tableCheck">
        <tr><th>Checks</th></tr>
        <tbody></tbody>
    </table>

    <input type="button" value="Add" class="btn btn-default" id="addCheck" />

    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
}
```

**add_check.js**

```
$(function () {
    $("#addCheck").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'Checklists/GenerateChecks',
            data: form.serialize()
        })
        .success(function (html) {
            var tableBody = document.getElementById('tableCheck').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
            tableBody.text(html);
        })
        .error(function (msg) {
            console.log(msg);
        });
    });
});
```

**Частичное представление**
_checklist.cshtml

```
@model TestManagementTools.Models.Checklist

@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Checks.Count; i++)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Checks[i].Value, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: И что? Что в консоли?

Comment: Функция по клику срабатывает, но запрос не посылается

Comment: Вы хотите сказать, что вызов `$.ajax({ ...` не делает ничего?

Comment: ReferenceError: form is not defined

Comment: <анонимная> http://localhost:49863/Scripts/add_check.js:6:13
 jQuery.event.dispatch http://localhost:49863/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.js:5200:16
 jQuery.event.add/elemData.handle http://localhost:49863/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.js:5009:6

Comment: и чему равна переменная form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Не знаю, какой версией jQuery Вы пользуетесь, но `jqXHR.success()` и `jqXHR.error()` устарели и убраны в версии 3.

Используйте:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'Checklists/GenerateChecks',
        data: $(this).closest("form").serialize(), // !!!
        success: function (html) {
          $('#tableCheck tbody').html(html);
        },
        error: function (msg) {
          console.log(msg);
        }
    });
```